# Boost MPI World Communicator duplication

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I'm looking for something similar to the question asked here: [MPI communicator as global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944534/c-mpi-communicator-as-global-variable).

The answer given there is essentially that `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is a global variable.

Boost wraps its communicators nicely, and generates a communicator wrapper for `MPI_COMM_WORLD` by default when constructing an object of type `boost::mpi::communicator`. [[Boost MPI tutorial]](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html)

**My question:**

If I want to access something given by the communicator, for example a process's rank, I can call

```
boost::mpi::communicator world;
int mpi_rank  = world.rank();
```

This will also work in a separate function, outside of `main.cpp`, etc. If I use the same constructor there, will I get the same `mpi_rank` value in each case? More specifically, will the process with `rank = 0` still have `rank = 0` if I construct a new `boost::mpi::communicator` object in a new file/function? It doesn't seem clear to me from the Boost documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: Looks like yes.

Example program (without relevant `#include`s, nice syntax):

```
int main()
{
    boost::mpi::communicator main_comm;
    int mpi_rank = main_comm.rank();
    myClass myObj;
    myObj.test(mpi_rank);
}

// Separate file
class myClass
{
    void test(int i) {
        boost::mpi::communicator local;
        int local_rank = local.rank();
        std::cout << "local rank = " << local_rank 
                  << ", i(main rank) = " << i 
                  << std::endl;
    }
};
```

This program always prints the same number twice (for always == 10 times, or so, with 4 processes. Not an exhaustive test by any means, but convincing for me at least)

Answer (score 0):

Confirming what you have already tested. Yes. Once you have set up an MPI communicator (or are using `MPI_COMM_WORLD` as in your case), a process' rank within that communicator will not change throughout the program. Even across files/functions.